# Triangle angle bisector and midpoints related question

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The question is :-

> **The bisector of each angle of a triangle intersects the opposite side at a point equidistant from the midpoints of other sides of the triangle. Find all such triangles.**

According to the question in $\Delta ABC$ I marked the midpoints as $A',B',C'.$ therefore let the bisector from $A$ be $AX$ hence
 $C'X =B'X$ therefore we need to find in which triangle does that happen.But I am confused how to move further to find which type of triangle is that.

Please help out to solve this question .It is an olympiad book question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AB=2c$, $BC=2a$ and $AC=2b$ be the sides of a triangle, $D$ and $E$ the midpoints of $BC$ and $AC$. Point $M$ on side $AB$, equidistant from $D$ and $E$, lies on the perpendicular bisector of $DE$, hence $HM={1\over2}DE={1\over2}c$. Moreover:
$$
BH=a\cos(\angle ABC)={a^2+c^2-b^2\over2c}={c\over2}+{a^2-b^2\over2c}
$$
and
$$
BM=BH+HM={c}+{a^2-b^2\over2c},\quad AM=2c-BM={c}-{a^2-b^2\over2c}.
$$
Point $M$ lies on the bisector of $\angle C$ if $BM:AM=BC:AC$, that is if:
$$
(a-b)\big(2c^2-(a+b)^2\big)=0.
$$
This is satisfied if either $a=b$ (isosceles triangle) or $(a+b)^2=2c^2$. Analogous equations hold for the other sides of the triangle.

If the triangle we are looking for is not isosceles, its sides must then satisfy the system
$$
\cases{
(a+b)^2=2c^2\\
(b+c)^2=2a^2\\
(c+a)^2=2b^2\\
}
$$
which has no positive solution, because summing up the three equation one gets 
$2ab+2bc+2ac=0$.

If the triangle is isosceles but not equilateral (e.g. $a=b\ne c$), the second and third equation coalesce into $(a+c)^2=2a^2$, which gives a solution: 
$$
{a\over c}=1+\sqrt2.
$$ 
Finally, we also have the trivial solution $a=b=c$.

[image]